# Remove random strings from an array , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, structure

I need to remove strings from an array and i have this function;
It makes some random tests and returns a result.

```
function filter_list(array) {
 array.filter((elem) => typeof elem === "string");
 return (array);
}
```

When i don't return anything i get undefined (obviously), but when i return the array i get this:

```
"Expected: '[1, 2]', instead got: '[1, 2, \'a\', \'b\']'
Expected: '[1, 0, 15]', instead got: '[1, \'a\', \'b\', 0, 15]'
Expected: '[1, 2, 123]', instead got: '[1, 2, \'aasf\', \'1\', \'123\', 
123]'
Expected: '[]', instead got: '[\'a\', \'b\', \'1\']'
Expected: '[1, 2]', instead got: '[1, 2, \'a\', \'b\']' "
```

Comment: If your numbers don't include +/-infinity, you could use `array.filter(Number.isFinite)`. If your numbers are all integers, use `array.filter(Number.isInteger)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy though. Here's how you will do it

```js
let data = [
  "Cat",
  1451,
  14.52,
  true,
  "I will be removed too :("
];


let filteredData =  data.filter(item => typeof item !== "string");

console.log(filteredData); // or return it
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing twice the [`array filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The first problem is that the array doesn't change when you call filter.

```
// This code isn't the correct yet, continue below
function filter_list(array) {
  // You have to return the result of filter. The 'array' is not changed.
  return array.filter((elem) => typeof elem === "string");
}
```

The second problem is that you are filtering the opposite you want to filter.

```
// Correct code
function filter_list(array) {
  // If the condition is true, the element will be kept in the NEW array.
  // So it must be false for strings
  return array.filter((elem) => typeof elem !== "string");
}
```

> `filter()` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in
>   an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which
>   `callback` returns a value that coerces to `true`. `callback` is invoked
>   only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not
>   invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been
>   assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the `callback` test
>   are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your help!!